# Erro na conta de raiz math.sqrt com multiplicação e divisão

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo uma interface com botões no Python, porem depois de escrever a conta deu erro... tentei refazer e está dando erro de indentação. O que preciso é o código está correto?

Segue o código!

```
try:
    DEMANDA=float(self.DEMANDA.get())
    CUSTOAQUISAO=float(self.CUSTOAQUISAO.get())
    CUSTOUNITARIO =float(self.CUSTOUNITARIO.get())
    TAXAARMAZENAGEM = float(self.FRETE.get())
    Qe=(math.sqrt((2*(DEMANDA*CUSTOAQUISAO)/(CUSTOUNITARIO/TAXAARMAZENAGEM)))
        s="O Lote Econômico é composto por         peças  "
        s=s+str(Qe)
        print (Qe)
except:
    s="Erro"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema... separei as contas e dei novos nomes para as variáveis,segue para auxiliar a quem precisar.

```
try:
    VAR1=float(self.VAR1.get())
    VAR2=float(self.VAR2.get())
    VAR3=float(self.VAR3.get())
    VAR4=float(self.VAR4.get())
    VAR5=(2*(VAR1*VAR2))
    VAR6=(VAR3*VAR4)
    VAR7=(math.sqrt(VAR5/VAR6))

    s="O Lote Econômico é composto por peças  "
    s=s+str(round(VAR7))+"peças"

except:
    s="Erro"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Qe=(math.sqrt((2*(DEMANDA*CUSTOAQUISAO)/(CUSTOUNITARIO/TAXAARMAZENAGEM)))
        s="O Lote Econômico é composto por         peças  " # identado errado a partir daqui
        s=s+str(Qe)
        print (Qe)
```

Python é uma linguagem onde a identação faz parte da sintaxe, ou seja, o programador é obrigado a identar o código para que ele tenha o sentido esperado.

No seu código vc inicia uma nova identação sem necessidade, talvez por engano, volte essas 3 linhas para a identação inicial e tente executá-lo novamente.

```
    try:
        DEMANDA=float(self.DEMANDA.get())
        CUSTOAQUISAO=float(self.CUSTOAQUISAO.get())
        CUSTOUNITARIO =float(self.CUSTOUNITARIO.get())
        TAXAARMAZENAGEM = float(self.FRETE.get())
        Qe=(math.sqrt((2*(DEMANDA*CUSTOAQUISAO)/(CUSTOUNITARIO/TAXAARMAZENAGEM)))
        s="O Lote Econômico é composto por         peças  "
        s=s+str(Qe)
        print (Qe)
    except:
        s="Erro"
```

O resultado deve ser +- assim, se ainda tiver dando erro, provavelmente será outra mensagem de erro.

Comment: Oi Gabriel, ainda continua dando a mensagem de erro, não consegue calcular... arrumei a identação e mesmo assim dá erro.... não sei mais o que fazer